# Comments three dots not seen next to the Title Column in Share point list

Tags: sharepoint

I have a share point list where I want to see comments for each record when added by any user . Sharing the screenshot of my list. Next to the first column "Name", I do not see the three dots that signifies the comment . Please let me know what am I doing wrong.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANS0o.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint online when you select one item there will be a comment option for you to view comments.

[comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiPxW.jpg)

Please make sure you have allowed comments on list items.

List settings > Advanced settings > Comments > Allow comments on list items

[List settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3Sly.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, I do have the Comments option checked in the advanced setting and also view this option when a record is selected. But how do I know if a new comment gets added for any specific record. I have close to 100 rows or records in this list so need some prompt or email notification to know if new comment gets posted to any record